# Determining Probability from Specific Markov Transition Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am trying to solve the following:

Consider a Markov chain whose state space is $\mathbb{R}$. Let $P(x,A), x ∈ \mathbb{R},A ∈ \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, be the following Markov transition function, $P(x,A) = \lambda([x − 1/2,x + 1/2] \cap A)$,where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Assuming that the initial distribution is
concentrated at the origin, find $P(|\omega_{2}| ≤ 1/4).$

I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Is $\omega$ the Markov chain? If so, first find the conditional probability $P(|\omega_2| \le 1/4 \mid \omega_1)$. Then apply the law of total probability.

Comment: I believe $\omega_{i}$ is the states of the Markov chain.  How can I apply the law of total probability here?

Comment: After computing the conditional probability above, the desired probability will be given by $E (P(|\omega_2| \le 1/4 \mid \omega_1))$, where the expectation is with respect to $\omega_1$.

Comment: I'm totally lost how I even apply the Markov transition function here.  From your previous comments I know that $P(\omega_{2} \le 1/4 | \omega_{1})$ = $P( \omega_{2} \le 1/4 \cap \omega_{1})/P(\omega_{1})$.  Then I compute the expectation of this?  I'm not following the reasoning at all.

Comment: Hint: The position of the Markov chain at time $2$ is the sum $X_1+X_2$ of two i.i.d. random variables with known distribution. Confirmation hint: The result is $1-\left(1-\frac14\right)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The law of total probability and the Markov property imply that
\begin{equation}
P(\omega_2 \in A \mid \omega_0 = 0)
 =
\int P(\omega_2 \in A \mid \omega_1 = x) f_1(x) \; dx,
\end{equation}
where $f_1$ is the conditional probability density function of $\omega_1$ given $\omega_0 = 0$ (assume for now that such a density exists and try to find it later). To explain my earlier comment, define the function $F(x) = P(\omega_2 \in A \mid \omega_1 = x)$. Then by the definition of the expectation of a function of a random variable with a density, the right-hand side of the equation above is simply $E[F(\omega_1)]$.

Now to evaluate the integral (which we've seen is an expectation), we need to find the density $f_1$ and the function $F$ defined above. But the function $F$ is just the transition function $P(x, A)$, which you've been given.

To find the conditional density, follow the "usual" procedure: First, find the conditional cumulative distribution function $F_1(x) = P(\omega_1 \le x \mid \omega_0 = 0)$. Then the conditional density is the derivative: $f_1(x) = F'_1(x)$.

Comment: This makes sense so far.  In terms of calculating $F_{1}(x), we know that $P(x,A) = \lambda([x − 1/2,x + 1/2] \cap A)$.  How do I take a derivative of a measure and plug it into the integral expression above?

Comment: You can compute $P(x, A)$ for $A = (-\infty, x]$ explicitly. The result is a function of $x$ that is piecewise differentiable (hint: there are three pieces) so there is no need to differentiate a measure.

Comment: Sorry but $P(x,A)$ for $A=(-\infty,x]$ is not made of three pieces, actually, $P(x,(-\infty,x])=\frac12$ for every $x$. Let me add that your answer makes for a strange reading, as if you were compiling general facts, mostly true, about general Markov chains without ever solving the case at hand...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $P(0, A)$, not $P(x, A)$, since $F_1(x) = P(0, A)$. Thanks for pointing that out. As to my answer, it's not meant to be a complete solution. The user who posted the question stated that they had no idea how to solve it, so I thought it might be best to just outline the main steps and to leave the details to them.